# Install Debian from the hard disk replacing the host Linux system

Tags: debian, boot, boot-loader, debian-installer

I have a old computer that i want to re-purpose into a storage server running debian, as i'm already used to it, but the problem is that the computer is runing Ubuntu and the BIOS only reads floppy disks and CD's. As my only solution is to install from the HDD, but i have a problem since GRUB 2 doesn't load the installer, i made the `/boot/newinstall` folder on the partition, added the kernel, the ramdisk and the iso image, also modified the `grub.cfg` to add a new menu entry to start the installer, but when i choose it, the screen goes black and restarts, maybe because i changed the extention to the image from `boot.img` to `boot.iso`.

Comment: Did you try to follow the instructions linked into http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222260/bootstrapping-up-from-an-old-debian-4-installation/222387#222387?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

- Burn one of the [Debian Net Installer CD images](//www.debian.org/CD/netinst/) to a CD and boot and install from that.
- Boot from any [CD/DVD installer image stored on a local file system](/q/199339/47852).

The first option is probably easier. You can even use a re-writable CD, if you're concerned about that.