# Installing Debian 8 (Jessie) from HDD Partition

Tags: debian, partition, system-installation, hard-disk, sd-card

I tried to install Debian 8 (Jessie) with the official DVD 1 from my Card Reader (SDHC UHS-I Card 32GB). Now that does not work, because I am unable to mount it (no signal at all).

Now I want to know if there is a way to install it from another HDD partition. I already made it FAT32 and put the files there, but the installer asks for a CD/DVD. Is there another installer that does take the files from the internal partition?

Also how do I remove the already started installation? I'm a bit straggled and can't find info about my problem.

-

**#### edit ####**

I started out formatting my SDHC card to Fat32, putting the whole installer disk on it, making it bootable (does not boot). So I found the **setup.exe** on the DVD which lead me through the installation process. After rebooting, the installation progress starts and it tells me to either run an automatic search for a CDROM input or manually enter it -> **nothing found**

So I randomly guess around with tty3, 4 until I give up and run the shell.

With **ls dev** there is a list of possible drives. **rtc0** looks nice, because my cardreader is an **Realtek RTS5209**. When I try to mount it, it says it is empty.

Now with **lspci -v** I found nothing usable for me.

So I made a new partition in FAT32 style, put the contents of the DVD there and mounted it using

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sda5/ /media/
```

Works like a charm, except that the installer does still ask for a CD / DVD source.

When I try to mount **sr0** again, it says something about must be blocked device.

Comment: Some more information will help get a better answer quicker.  Did you boot a USB drive into Linux? Where and how and what are you trying to mount it.  What is giving no signal?  What files did you put on the partition?  What commands did you use?  Telling the commands you used, and the output you've seen is critical to getting an answer here.  I don't think you need to be concerned with removing anything from the partitions yet, it might not matter because if you do a successful install it will erase everything anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I added some more information in the post.

Comment: The links in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222260/bootstrapping-up-from-an-old-debian-4-installation/222387#222387 should lead you to a usable recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to download the **USB** ISO file. Else, you can burn your current **DVD** ISO on a DVD and proceed to install.